# Symbol confusion in dynamic linked library when app code has same symbol

Tags: c, shared-libraries, symbols

The scenario I have is a bit complicated.

I have an application `main.c`, in it, a function `a()` is defined. The app is dynamically linked to library `lib1.so`, which in turn is linked to `lib2.so`. In `lib2.so`, another instance of `a()` is defined and called internally by `lib2Func()`.

Now after I built and linked main with `lib1.so`, in turn link `lib1.so` with `lib2.so`. Yet when the program is running, I noticed that when `lib2Func()` is calling `a()`, it didn't call the instance from `lib2.so`, instead, it was calling the instance from `main.c`.

How did the symbol confusion takes place? I thought each dynamic library is loaded into its own memory block? And is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: there is teh '-Bsymbolic' ld qual which is supposed to change the resolution for shared libs when they are created. Check man pages for `ld`

Comment: @Serge I have already added `-Bsymbolic` and `-Bsymbolic-functions` into linking argument when creating `lib1.so` and `lib2.so`. It didn't prevent `lib2` from using `a()` defined in `main.c`